# How to update an .apk that contains two SHA1 fingerprints?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, keystore, sign

I took over an existing Android app together with a keystore file to sign it, but signing and uploading the app causes the following error:

```
Upload failed 
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous
APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the
certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): 
    [ SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,
      SHA1: YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY ]
    and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s): 
      SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

One thing that's odd here is that the fingerprint of the certificate I used to sign the .apk file (XX) is listed the existing APKs fingerprints. Now I wonder, do I need to sign the APK file with a second certificate in order to be able to update it at playstore? I.e was the original version (the one currently in Playstore) signed twice? Is there any way to use only one of the two certificates for future updates? 
Any clarification is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please download KEYSTORE EXPLORER and open your .jks file with it and there you can see which certificate contains the signature you used to signed the apk in the play store.